# insertion sort using linked list for Book objects

Tags: java, linked-list, insertion-sort

I'm trying to use insertion sort to sort linked list of Book alphabetically  by title.

what I have done so far:

```
 public void insertSorted(Book book){
     if(books.getfirst()==null)
         books.addFirst(book); //books is the LinkedList name
     Node<Book> current =books.getfirst();
     for(int i=0; i<books.getSize(); i++){
        if(book.getTitle().compareToIgnoreCase(current.element.getTitle())<=0){
             books.add(book, i);

         }
     }
```

the add method in Linkedlist:

```
public void add(Object x,int index){
    if(index==0)addFirst(x);
    else if(index>=getSize())addLast(x);
    else{
        Node current=first;
        for(int i=0; i<index-1;i++)
            current=current.next;
        Node temp = new Node(x);
        temp.next=current.next;
        current.next=temp;
        count++;
    }
}
```

what exactly I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In the for loop of insertSorted you should check against book[i]. Nothing in the if statement depends on i.

Comment: it repeat the first book twice, is there something wrong with the loop??

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0; i<books.getSize(); i++){
    if(book.getTitle().compareToIgnoreCase(current.element.getTitle())<=0){
         books.add(book, i);

     }
```

With this statement (above), you are not incrementing the current `Node` which is being compared. On each iteration of the `for(;;)` loop, you are comparing the new `Book` which is being added to this first element in the `List`.

The below code example should fix this:

```
for(int i=0; i<books.getSize(); i++){
    if(book.getTitle().compareToIgnoreCase(current.element.getTitle())<=0){
         books.add(book, i);
         break;
     }
    else {
        current = current.next;
    }
```

EDIT: Included required break statement, as per @Eden Lu answer

Answer (score 1):

After you add the book to books, you need to break the loop

books.add(book,i);
break;

Comment: otherwise it is gonna add the same books multiple times